# How can I append this value in addition to what the user inputs?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that implements `FindNext` in order to search a sheet for a row to match two column values that the user inputs via `Application.InputBox`. Works flawlessly. But there is an instance where I'd like one of the msgboxs to display another cell value in that row without the user input.

Example: User inputs Job code `000001` found in column A, cost-center `100100010001` Found in column C.

The msgbox will match it and say: `MsgBox "Job Code (" & lJobCode & ") is eligible for this cost-center.`

What if I also wanted that message box to add in a value found in another column, but automatically? Like, without the user input because they wouldn't know this info off hand.

New MsgBox Example: `MsgBox "Job Code (" & lJobCode & ") is eligible for this (" & Column H Value for this row & ") cost-center.`

I was thinking something like a `str` variable and reference the column, but I'm having trouble having VBA trigger that value once the row is matched.

Rest of script:

```
Option Explicit
Sub findJC_CC()

Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim rFound As Range
Dim lJobCode As String
Dim lCC As String
Dim sFirst As String
Dim matched As Boolean

lJobCode = Application.InputBox("Please provide a job code", "Job Code", Type:=2)
If lJobCode = "False" Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel
lCC = Application.InputBox("Please enter in a cost-center", "CC", Type:=2)
If lCC = "False" Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

matched = False
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set rFound = wsData.Columns("A").Find(lJobCode, wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole)

If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
    sFirst = rFound.Address
    Do

        If rFound.Offset(, 2).Value = lCC Then
            matched = True

            'if criteria is met, display msgbox and exit
            If rFound.Offset(, 4).Value = "Exempt" Then
                MsgBox "The business identified this exempt job as being eligible for schedule pay allowance ."
                Exit Sub
            End If

            'if criteria is met, display msgbox and exit
            If rFound.Offset(, 5).Value = "Eligible - Employee Level" Then
                MsgBox "This job is only eligible at the employee level. If you have further questions, please reach out to your HRBP."
                Exit Sub
            End If

            'if non-exempt role, and matched, display msgbox and exit
            MsgBox "Job Code (" & lJobCode & ") is eligible for this cost-center."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'loop after first address found until column C has lCC value matched
        Set rFound = wsData.Columns("A").FindNext(rFound)
    Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst

    'lJobCode value matched, lCC value not matched
    If Not matched Then MsgBox "Job Code (" & lJobCode & ") found, but not eligible for this cost-center."
Else

    'lJobCode not matched
    MsgBox "Job Code (" & lJobCode & ") not eligible."

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, the variable `rFound` points to a cell in column A from which you want to offset. If that's the case, you could write code like:

```
MsgBox "Job Code (" & lJobCode & ") is eligible for this (" & rFound.Offset(,7).Value & ") cost-center.
```

Comment: This was so obvious, can't believe I didn't think to just do that after seeing how the if statements were triggered, originally. Thanks a lot, going to try this now.

Comment: Solution verified!

Answer (score 0):

You can add that line:

```
Option Explicit
Sub findJC_CC()

Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim rFound As Range
Dim lJobCode As String
Dim lCC As String
Dim sFirst As String
Dim matched As Boolean

lJobCode = Application.InputBox("Please provide a job code", "Job Code", Type:=2)
If lJobCode = "False" Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel
lCC = Application.InputBox("Please enter in a cost-center", "CC", Type:=2)
If lCC = "False" Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

matched = False
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set rFound = wsData.Columns("A").Find(lJobCode, wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole)

If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
    sFirst = rFound.Address
    Do

        If rFound.Offset(, 2).Value = lCC Then
            matched = True

            'if criteria is met, display msgbox and exit
            If rFound.Offset(, 4).Value = "Exempt" Then
                MsgBox "The business identified this exempt job as being eligible for schedule pay allowance ."
                Exit Sub
            End If

            'if criteria is met, display msgbox and exit
            If rFound.Offset(, 5).Value = "Eligible - Employee Level" Then
                MsgBox "This job is only eligible at the employee level. If you have further questions, please reach out to your HRBP."
                Exit Sub
            End If

            'if non-exempt role, and matched, display msgbox and exit
            MsgBox "Job Code (" & lJobCode & ") is eligible for this (" & rFound.Offset(, 7).Value & ") cost-center."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'loop after first address found until column C has lCC value matched
        Set rFound = wsData.Columns("A").FindNext(rFound)
    Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst

    'lJobCode value matched, lCC value not matched
    If Not matched Then MsgBox "Job Code (" & lJobCode & ") found, but not eligible for this cost-center."
Else

    'lJobCode not matched
    MsgBox "Job Code (" & lJobCode & ") not eligible."

End If

End Sub
```